# How to extract text from an existing docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-docx

I'm trying to use `python-docx` module (`pip install python-docx`)
but it seems to be very confusing as in [github repo](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/tests/test_docx.py) test sample they are using `opendocx` function but in [readthedocs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) they are using `Document` class. Even though they are only showing how to add text to a docx file, not reading existing one?

1st one (`opendocx`) is not working, may be deprecated. For second case I was trying to use:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('test_doc.docx')
print(document.paragraphs)
```

It returned a list of `<docx.text.Paragraph object at 0x... >`

Then I did:

```
for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

It returned all text but there were few thing missing. All URLs (CTRL+CLICK to go to URL) were not present in text on console.

What is the issue? Why URLs are missing?

How could I get complete text without iterating over loop (something like `open().read()`)

Comment: Note the old GitHub repo https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx has 'This Project Has Moved!' in heading 1.

Comment: Also, all the numbered lists are not exported as text...

Answer (score 76):

you can try this

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

Comment: This is a good start, it does not reflect text in tables, in headers, in footers and in foot notes.

Comment: Consider using [simplify-docx](https://github.com/microsoft/Simplify-Docx) which based on python-docx and substantially reduces the complexity of the XML document  while keeping much of the structure (paragraphs, tables, headers, footers, etc.)

Comment: How is this different from what the questioner as a method? In fact it is even worse because it creates a stupid and useless list instead of a text!! 
And I see 59 upvotes for this!! They should actually be downvotes!  (I didn't downvote because I never do. I prefer instead to explain why replies like this one are really bad!)

Comment: indeed it just confirms that the question is hard to solve

Comment: fun one-liner: `'\n'.join([p.text for p in doc.paragraphs])`

Answer (score 27):

You can use [python-docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt) which is adapted from python-docx but can also extract text from links, headers and footers. It can also extract images.

Comment: this is a useful piece of code, but it's not export numbered lists.

Comment: thanks, [here is the tracking issue for this bug](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt/issues/12)

Comment: Updated version is in this package https://github.com/ShayHill/docx2python

Answer (score 18):

**Without Installing `python-docx`**

`docx` is basically is a zip file with several folders and files within it. In the link below you can find a simple function to extract the text from `docx` file, without the need to rely on `python-docx` and `lxml` the latter being sometimes hard to install:

http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/

Comment: I get this with your code "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file". Why would that be?

Comment: This code worked for me previously. Can you upload your docx file and provide a link that I can test it?

Comment: this still works, but .getiterator( has been deprecated and has to be replaced with .iter( now https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#removed

Answer (score 8):

There are two "generations" of python-docx. The initial generation ended with the 0.2.x versions and the "new" generation started at v0.3.0. The new generation is a ground-up, object-oriented rewrite of the legacy version. It has a [distinct repository located here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx).

The opendocx() function is part of the legacy API. The documentation is for the new version. The legacy version has no documentation to speak of.

<del>Neither reading nor writing hyperlinks are supported in the current version. That capability is on the roadmap, and the project is under active development. It turns out to be quite a broad API because Word has so much functionality. So we'll get to it, but probably not in the next month unless someone decides to focus on that aspect and contribute it.</del>  **UPDATE** Hyperlink support was added subsequent to this answer.

Comment: had this been fixed in the latest version - hard to tell from github

Answer (score 7):

Using python-docx, as @Chinmoy Panda 's answer shows:

```
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    fullText.append(para.text)
```

However, `para.text`  will lost the text in `w:smarttag` (Corresponding github issue is here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/328), you should use the following function instead:

```
def para2text(p):
    rs = p._element.xpath('.//w:t')
    return u" ".join([r.text for r in rs])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no official solution for this problem, but there is a workaround posted here
https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/python-docx/commit/afd9fef6b2636c196761e5ed34eb05908e582649

just update this file
"...\site-packages\docx\oxml_*init*_.py"

```
# add
import re
import sys

# add
def remove_hyperlink_tags(xml):
    if (sys.version_info > (3, 0)):
        xml = xml.decode('utf-8')
    xml = xml.replace('</w:hyperlink>', '')
    xml = re.sub('<w:hyperlink[^>]*>', '', xml)
    if (sys.version_info > (3, 0)):
        xml = xml.encode('utf-8')
    return xml
    
# update
def parse_xml(xml):
    """
    Return root lxml element obtained by parsing XML character string in
    *xml*, which can be either a Python 2.x string or unicode. The custom
    parser is used, so custom element classes are produced for elements in
    *xml* that have them.
    """
    root_element = etree.fromstring(remove_hyperlink_tags(xml), oxml_parser)
    return root_element
```

and of course don't forget to mention in the documentation that use are changing the official library