# How to extract paragraphs/sections under specific headline in word file?

Tags: python, ms-word

Here is my situation:
I have a .doc file which like this:

```
Headline 1

headline 1.1
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph

headline 1.2
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph




Headline 2

headline 2.1
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph

headline 2.2
paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph
```

And I want to extract the whole headline 1 section, how can I make it with python?

Comment: You should consider pasting the code you wrote when attempting to solve the task so that others can provide better help. Please refer to the help center on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract text from an existing docx file using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx)

Comment: Since docx files are basically zipped xml files you can also read them using ElementTree that ships with Python http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/