# Removing characters from docx file

Tags: python

I have a really big docx file(700 pages) it has a log format

```
[15/09/2014, 15:30:21] Stijn: Nice
```

I am looking to remove the time and let it look like this

```
[15/09/2014] Stijn: Nice
```

Im pretty sure that this can be done in python but just haven't figured out the exact way. 
I should be using something like this?

```
line.replace(char,'')
```

Its a whatsapp log file little it looks like this(Some text use 2 lines)

```
[15/09/2014, 15:53:39] Dylan: Beste selfie ever 
[15/09/2014, 15:53:52] Sipke: Ja 
[15/09/2014, 15:54:05] ‎You changed this group's icon
```

Help would be apreciated :)

Comment: I am not sure how your data is set up. If what you have in square brackets is a list on its own you can use .pop() to remove the last item from each list.

Comment: I think the quickest would be to zip open the docx and change the main xml file with a pattern replace.

Comment: .docx files are saved in a proprietary format that is not easy to change outside of word (try opening in notepad to see what i mean), you will have a lot of trouble using python to parse them. Is there any way you can use another format or even .txt files instead?

Comment: @Njord `.docx` is `XML`, hence the `x`.

Comment: My bad, I try to avoid working with .docx and the like, maybe this package could do what youre looking for: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx

Comment: Are you asking about how to edit each line? How about `line = line[:11] + line[22:]` or similar

Comment: Your question is very imprecise. Please tell us what exactly you're looking for. Is it how to open a word file? Is it how to change each line to your format? What aspect do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to use regular expressions, this can be done very easily. You want to:

1) Read the file line by line

2) **Substitute** the time stamp with blank text.

Here's a sample python code I whipped up for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

text = "[15/09/2014, 15:30:21] Stijn: Nice"

# Capture time stamp and substitute it with blank
new = re.sub(r'(, [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})', "", text)    
print new
```

This will yield:

```
[15/09/2014] Stijn: Nice
```

If you want to fiddle with/understand the usage of regex expression I used here, follow this link- https://regexr.com/406sc

Comment: Oh and also @Barkork, (depending on your data) you will have to modify the regex to make sure it doesn't perform a _greedy match_. In other words if a line item looks like:

`[15/09/2014, 15:30:21] Stijn: Nice, I timed my lap, 02:01:99 and you?`
the current pattern might remove ", 02:01:99" because it looked for every instance of that pattern in the given line.

Comment: `.docx` isn't just plain text, it's a zipped set of `.xml` files. There's more to this question than you realise.

Comment: @PeterWood I am aware about the docx format. However, it is not that tough to export a docx to a plain text file. Since in this case the data is just a chat log, it would seem that retaining the text formatting after clean up is redundant.
But I guess I should have mentioned that in the answer as well, and not assume things.
Some may find this link useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871416/4701044