# How to extract questions from a word doc with Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, ms-word, python-3.7

I am using docx library to read files from a word doc, I am trying to extract only the questions using regex search and match. I found infinite ways of doing it but I keep getting a "TypeError".

The data I am trying to extract is this:

Will my financial aid pay for housing? 
Off Campus Housing - After financial aid applies toward your tuition and
 fees, any remaining funds will be sent to you as a refund that will
 either be directly deposited (which can be set up through your 
account) or mailed to you as a paper check.  You can then use the
 refund to pay your rent.  It is important to note that financial aid may
 not be available when rent is due, so make sure to have a plan in 
place to pay your rent. Will my financial aid pay for housing?
"financial" "help" "house"
funds "univ oak"
"money" "chisho"
"pay" "chap"
"grant" "laurel"
What are the requirements to receive a room and grant?
How do I pay for my housing?
How do I pay for housing?

If there's also an easier method of exporting the word doc into a different type of file, that'll be great to know for feedback. Thank you

I am using regex 101, I've tried the following regex expressions to match only the sentences that end in a question mark

```
".*[?=?]$"
"^(W|w).*[?=?]$"
"^[A-Za-z].*[?=?]$"
```

```
import re
import sys
from docx import Document

wordDoc = Document('botDoc.docx')

result = re.search('.*[?=?]$', wordDoc)
print(result)
if result:
    print(result.group(0))
for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print("test")
```

I expect to save the matching patterns into directories so I can export the data to a csv file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your error:**

```
result = re.search('.*[?=?]$', wordDoc)
```

I believe that this line is the cause of the problem. `search()` is expecting a string as a second parameter, but is receiving a Document object.

What you should do is use the `findall()` function. `search()` only finds the first match for a pattern; `findall()` finds **all** the matches and returns them as a list of strings, with each string representing one match.

Since you are working with docx, you would have to extract the contents of the docx and use them as second parameter of the `findall()` method. If I remember correctly, this is done by first extracting all the paragraphs, and then extracting the text of the individual paragraphs. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx) question.

FYI, the way you would do this for a simple text file is the following:

```
# Open file
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
# Feed the file text into findall(); it returns a list of all the found strings
strings = re.findall(r'your pattern', f.read())
```

**Your Regex:**

Unfortunately, your regex is not quite correct, because although logically it makes sense to match only sentences that end on a `?`, one of your matches is `place to pay your rent. Will my financial aid pay for housing?`, for example. Only the second part of that sentence is an actual question. So discard any lower case letters. Your regex should be something like:

```
[A-Z].*\?$
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I now understand what was I doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: Hello sir and thanks for your answer, i have a corpus of documents containing questions with their answers, my problem is similar to this question, i have a machine learning project and so far i only used a naive approach to do the task, but i'd like to know if there is another way to do it, thanks for your response.