# Python - grab all text in .docx and dump into .txt

Tags: text, python, parsing

I am wondering how I would write a Python script to carry out the following set of steps: (1) open a typical .docx, (2) select all, (3) copy to clipboard, (4) store as a string.

I don't care about preserving any formatting, nor about graphics, nor about tables. I just want the text stored as a gigantic string, for parsing and analysis.

Comment: there is a package called docx2txt that can read from word document. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about a docx you could consider using python-docx
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

According to the documentation you could write something like this

```
def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

To get all the text then using something like `pyperclip` you could copy it to clipboard.
So without trying it i would imagine something like

```
import docx
import pyperclip

textInFile = getText("yourDoc.docx")
pyperclip.copy(textInFile)
```

https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries to help with this. Take a look at `python-docx`, which despite being oriented towards creating and updating `docx` files will allow you to read the contents of a document.

This answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871416/11996110) might help you start, but is by no means complete.

Here's a link to the [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) documentation.