# Read in whole text as string to list instead of each paragraph

Tags: python, string, list, docx

I read in a docx document and appended each paragraph to a list as a string using this code:

```
from docx import Document
paragraphs = []

document = Document('/path to/*.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    para = para.text
    paragraphs.append(para)
```

Instead reading in each paragraph I would like to read in the whole text as one string and append it to a list. How do I have to modify the code above?

Comment: Have you looked to see what else is available from `document`?

Comment: So you just want the full document text as a single item in a list?

Comment: Yes, the full document text

Comment: Similar answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871416/6317430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate all the paragraphs in a variable and then you can store the complete text in a list by appending as follows:

```
from docx import Document
text_com=""
paragraphs = []

document = Document('/path to/*.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    text_com += para.text

paragraphs.append(text_com)
```