# Python3 Docx get text between 2 paragraphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-docx

i have .docx files in a directory and i want to get all text between two paragraphs.

**Example:**

> Foo : 
>
> The foo is not easy, but we have to do it.
> We are looking for new things in our ad libitum way of life. 
>
> Bar :

I want to get :

```
The foo is not easy, but we have to do it.
We are looking for new things in our ad libitum way of life.
```

I wrote this code :

```py
import docx
import pathlib
import glob
import re

def rf(f1):
    reader = docx.Document(f1)
    alltext = []
    for p in reader.paragraphs:
        alltext.append(p.text)
    return '\n'.join(alltext)


for f in docxfiles:
    try:
        fulltext = rf(f)
        testf = re.findall(r'Foo\s*:(.*)\s*Bar', fulltext, re.DOTALL)
        
        print(testf)
    except IOError:
        print('Error opening',f)
```

it returns `None`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well . you do not return anything from `rf1` .. so None is returned... also : NameError on docxfiles. also: did you `print(p.text)`  and see if it may match your regex at all?

Comment: Perhaps try `re.DOTALL` like `fread = re.search(r'Foo\s*:(.*?)\s*Bar', p.text, re.DOTALL)` with a non greedy dot.

Comment: thanks for your answers.  @Patrick if i do `print(p.text)` it returns all the text in the document.

Comment: @the fourth bird i tried but still have `None`

Comment: If you print the result of `p.text` and copy paste it here https://regex101.com/r/xUq0os/1 do you get a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop over all paragraphs and print paragraphs texts you get the document text as is - but the **single** `p.text` of your loop does not contain the full documents text.

It works with a string:

```
t = """Foo :

The foo is not easy, but we have to do it. We are looking for new things in our ad libitum way of life.

Bar :"""
      
import re
      
fread = re.search(r'Foo\s*:(.*)\s*Bar', t)
      
print(fread)  # None  - because dots do not match \n
     
fread = re.search(r'Foo\s*:(.*)\s*Bar', t, re.DOTALL)
      
print(fread)
print(fread[1])
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 115), match='Foo :\n\nThe foo is not easy, but we have to do i>


The foo is not easy, but we have to do it. We are looking for new things in our ad libitum way of life.
```

If you use

```
for p in reader.paragraphs:
    print("********")
    print(p.text)
    print("********")
```

you see why your regex wont match. Your regex *would* work on the whole documents text.

See [How to extract text from an existing docx file using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx)  how to get the whole docs text.

You could as well look for a paragraph that matches `r'Foo\s*:'` - then put all following paragraph.text's into a list until you hit a paragraph that matches `r'\s*Bar'`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I needed to get my mind put in the right way (friday morning).