# Generate an image from a word file and limit the image to the text in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

My need is to get an image of the text in a word file using Python. The text length changes with every file. How can I detect the text and take a screenshot or generate an image of that text without including the whitespace from the rest of the document? The text can span multiple lines.

[Here is an example of the word file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCz3K.png)

[And this is the result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk4Sy.png)

I'm writing a script that reads the word file, takes a screenshot as above, and then saves it to a location.

EDIT: SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text you could use any of the many solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx)

After that to create a new image, you can use PIL, here some more examples
https://notebooks.ai/santiagobasulto/how-to-generate-images-with-text-using-python-and-pil-bcd5d188
https://code-maven.com/create-images-with-python-pil-pillow

Comment: I should add that there can be equations as well, so reading those as a text will change the format. Is there any way to detect text and take a screenshot.