# How to read data from .docx file in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a word file (.docx) containing comma separated data as shown in format below:

```
Id,Firstname,Lastname,Salary,Department  
1,ABC,XYZ,10000,ENG  
2,DEF,XYZ,20000,FIN
```

I want to read this comma separated data directly as a dataframe in pandas. Please help.
I have already found a way to convert this data into an excel .csv file and then use pd.read_csv function in pandas. But, wanted to know if direct data import from .docx would be possible or not?

TIA!

Comment: `import docx` perhaps

Comment: you can use the docx library : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), and [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import docx
import io
import pandas as pd

content = docx.Document('data.docx').paragraphs[0].text
# or if all paragraphs
# content = '\n'.join([p.text for p in docx.Document('data.docx').paragraphs

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(content))
```

output:

```
   Id Firstname Lastname  Salary Department
0   1       ABC      XYZ   10000        ENG
1   2       DEF      XYZ   20000        FIN
```